# Using static html pages in Angular2

Tags: angular

In my Angular2 project I use authentication flow via oidc-client-js and to receive tokens from Auth server i put silent-renew.html page in my src folder.
Also i add it to angular-cli.json file:

```
 "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "{ "glob": "silent-renew.html", "input": "./", "output": "./" }"
  ]
```

So, i suppose file silent-renew.html to be available at http://localhost:4200/silent-renew.html but i have mistake: Cannot GET /silent-renew.html. How to make this static html to be visible for Angular?

Comment: More than angular it matters who is gonna serve you the resource.

Comment: [may be this article will help](https://medium.com/@feloy/building-a-static-website-with-angular-universal-a1acc49e26e5)

Comment: Thank you, rainmak3r, i will try to use this approach

Comment: I use  oidc-client-js and have a similar config. Even the example project does too https://github.com/jmurphzyo/Angular2OidcClient/blob/28a8b0be0a36b9b1df9cc291f41a87048d12a4b2/.angular-cli.json#L15 How are you hosting or serving?

Comment: Yes, for example project it work well but when i use it for my real project i have 'Cannot GET' mistake. Even if i try to launch it without server.